# Equation labeling in latex

Tags: cross-referencing

I need referencing from an equation, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
 y+x=3
\end{equation}
 some text \ref{eq:1} some text  
\end{document}
```

will result in:
'some text Eq.(1) some text'. Not just number, but with Eq. or 'Equation' insert before the number in brackets.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you use `amssymb` and `amsmath`, I suggest to use `\eqref{eq:1}` instead of `\ref{eq:1}`, but I can't reproduce `Eq.(1)`. There must be something in between

Comment: I've tried already, it only produce (1) and not Eq.(1).

Comment: So what's the question then, if it does not show `Eq.(1)`?

Comment: I need the referencing in the text to be 'Eq.(1)', not just '(1)'.

Comment: Sorry, that was *not* clear from your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
 y+x=3
\end{equation}
 some text \cref{eq:1} some text
\end{document}
```

[image]